# how to use Gradle dependency .so file

Tags: android, maven, gradle

In maven project i can

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.epwk.armeabi-v7a</groupId>
        <artifactId>libjpush170</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>so</type>
        <classifier>armeabi-v7a</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

now i want to use gradle

```
compile 'com.epwk.armeabi-v7a:libjpush170:1.0:armeabi-v7a@so'
```

but it's build error.
How should I do

Comment: It is not a jar file

Comment: Try `'com.epwk:liblocSDK4d:1.0:armeabi'` and `'com.epwk:liblocSDK4d:1.0:armeabi@so'`. If that doesn't work, check the `--info` log.